# An async_group class to gather futures and clean them periodically

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++14

Here the short story. I have a listener on a queue which sends me several jobs. Each job is launched in a thread and takes different times to finish. I have two main constraints :

- I want to retrieve the result of the job when it finishes (hence the use of `std::async` rather than `std::thread`)
- I want to have a collection of threads in the same kind of way as [boost:thread_group](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup) but I cannot use a `join_all`/`get_all` method since I do not know when the job finishes and I do not want to be blocked.

So the idea chosen was to use the `clean_ready_futures` method which goes through the vector periodically and remove the ready futures such as proposed on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531096/can-i-use-stdasync-without-waiting-for-the-future-limitation).

**async_group.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>

template<typename R>
bool is_future_ready(std::future<R> const& f) { 
    return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready; 
}

template <typename T>
struct async_group {
    std::vector<std::future<T>> futures;

    async_group()                               = default;
    async_group(const async_group&)             = delete;
    async_group& operator=(const async_group&)  = delete;
    async_group(async_group &&)                 = delete;

    // not working yet
    // template<class Function, class... Args>
    // void create_future(Function&& f, Args&&... args)  { 
    //     futures.emplace_back(std::async(
    //         std::launch::async,
    //         std::forward<Function>(f),
    //         std::forward<Args>(args)...
    //     ));
    // }
    void add_future(std::future<T>&& ret) { 
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex}; 
        futures.emplace_back(std::move(ret)); 
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return futures.size(); }

    // Use this to have a similar behaviour as join_all()
    std::vector<T> get_all() {
        auto result = std::vector<T>{};
        result.reserve(size());
        for (auto & f : futures) {
            result.push_back(f.get());
        }
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        futures.clear();
        return result;
    }

    // Use this periodicall if you don't want to call get() and "detach" the asyncs
    std::vector<T> clean_ready_futures() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        // erase from futures vector and store ready futures in finished results
        auto finished_results = std::vector<T>{};
        futures.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                futures.begin(),
                futures.end(),
                [&finished_results](auto& f) -> bool {
                    if (is_future_ready(f)) { // future is ready then
                        finished_results.emplace_back(f.get()); // store the ready future in results
                        return true; // erase it from pending futures
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            ),
            futures.end()
        );

        return finished_results;
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
};
```

**illustative usage**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "async_group.hpp"

std::string foo() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{200});
    return "foo";
}

std::string bar() {
    return "bar";
}

async_group<std::string>  pending_futures;

void launch_jobs() {
    pending_futures.add_future(std::async(std::launch::async, foo));
    pending_futures.add_future(std::async(std::launch::async, bar));
}

void clean_ready_jobs() {
    auto results = pending_futures.clean_ready_futures();
    std::cout << "Clean ready jobs: ";
    for (auto const& r : results) {
        std::cout << r << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void get_all_jobs() {
    auto results = pending_futures.get_all();
    std::cout << "Clean ready jobs: ";
    for (auto const& r : results) {
        std::cout << r << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    launch_jobs();
    get_all_jobs(); // both foo and bar should be done
    launch_jobs();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{10});
    clean_ready_jobs(); // bar should be done
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{200});
    clean_ready_jobs(); // foo should be done
}
```

[Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7hZtMbXdq3ytcgKl)

Have I missed something ? How can this be improved ? I am looking forward to your insights.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.2 and the line `if (is_future_ready(f)) { // future is ready then` doesn't compile, while this may be a problem in my compiler, auto isn't guaranteed to work in lambda expressions arguments until C++14 according to everything I can find on the web. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709894/using-auto-in-a-lambda-function.

Comment: Yes I will precise the C++14 tag. If you put `[&finished_results](std::future<T>& f)` instead of `[&finished_results](auto& f)` it will work

Answer (score 1):

We are assuming this is a multi threaded environemnt.

Thus all methods need to guard against access by a different thread and lock access to members.

```
// There is no lock here:
std::size_t size() const { return futures.size(); }

// There is no lock here:
std::vector<T> get_all() {
```

Comment: So adding `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};`at the top scope of the method definition will do the work right ?

Comment: @coincoin: Yes.